# Flutter plugin `geolocator-Swift.h` file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-plugin

I have created a small Flutter plugin which can be used to monitor location changes in you Flutter application (source: https://github.com/baseflowit/flutter-geolocator). After extensive testing using the example project that is part of the project structure (as generated by the Flutter CLI) we decided to publish the plugin to make it available to the world.

Now we received some feedback that when you include the package from the online Dart Packages repo into your Flutter App, the iOS version doesn't compile and returns the following exception:

```
/Users/maurits/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-0.0.2/ios/Classes/GeolocatorPlugin.m:2:9:
fatal error: 'geolocator/geolocator-Swift.h' file not found
```

This error occurs when running the Flutter App in debug mode, but also when making a iOS package using `flutter build ios --release`.

I am a bit lost where this error comes from since the `example` app that is part of the `Geolocator` project works without any problems. I know the `geolocator/geolocator-Swift.h` file is autogenerated, so to me it looks like that the file doesn't end up in the final Dart Package. To run the final Dart Package I ran the following command:

`flutter packages pub publish`

Here is the output of `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.5 17F77, locale en-NL)
    • Flutter version 0.5.1 at /Users/maurits/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision c7ea3ca377 (4 weeks ago), 2018-05-29 21:07:33 +0200
    • Engine revision 1ed25ca7b7
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/maurits/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/maurits/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.4.1, Build version 9F2000
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 25.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[!] VS Code (version 1.24.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • iPhone X • 69C349CF-81E1-47E8-B35A-A149D885CE43 • ios • iOS 11.4 (simulator)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please update Flutter and then check. i faced same issue just updated my flutter and error gone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the plugin is written using Swift, the consuming Flutter app should be based on the Swift project template:

```
$ flutter create -i swift my_app
```

Adding `geolocator:` to the `pubspec.yaml` and building `my_app` for iOS then works for me using the latest Flutter beta.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.5 17F77, locale en-US)
```

Comment: If you have already created the app without specifying the `-i swift` argument, what needs to be changed in order to get this to run?

Comment: @keithbhunter no I guess. add `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile.

Answer (score 20):

you go to Ios/Podfile
add the following line:

```
use_frameworks! # required by Geolocator
```

Like the following

Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.

```
use_frameworks! # required by Geolocator
system('rm -rf .symlinks')
system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
```

After this add

```
config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
```

Like the following:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2' # added this
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why is this necessary?  While I think this is a workaround, what is the real underlying bug and which project needs to address it?

Comment: Because "geolocator" lib using Swift (not Ojbect-C), it requires you to "use_frameworks" in the Podfile and SWIFT_VERSION must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. Maybe 3.0, 4.1 and 4.2, you can try

Answer (score 0):

Small addition when error: Module 'geocoder' not found

Instead of the "Runner.xcodeproj" file, you need to run the "Runner.xcworkspace" file

Comment: You **always** need to use `.xcworkspace` when you're using CocoaPods. This is not specific to this question or to this specific error.